# How to implement connected component labelling for 3d data?

Tags: python, image-processing, 3d, voxel, connected-components

While searching/reading , I found [connected component labelling (2 Pass algorithm)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling) which is for 2D data sets. I have to implement connected component labelling for 3d(voxel) dataset. In 2d connected component labelling, we are checking for the left most and top most pixels(neighbours) for equivalent labelling. How can we implement it for 3d dataset using python that is which neighbours should be checked for labelling?

or is there any other way where i can get the implementation of it , please do suggest.

Comment: Same thing, but check also the neighbors in the plane you've already visited. With this algorithm, you always check all the neighbors that you have already visited and labeled. Knowing that, you should be able to figure it out for any number of dimensions.

Comment: how to check the neighbors in the plane which are already visited? can't imagine which nodes to check for labelling and equivalence point to be added for 3D?

Comment: using data frames of pandas -python , it can be easily implemented : df[(df['longitude'] == x) & (df['latitude'] == y) &(df['temperature'] == z)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can implement connected component labelling for 3D (voxel) in the same way as it is implemented for 2d except that along with the left and top voxel, we have to check the front voxel for the equivalence  label.